# How to serialize 2 letter sting in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, ascii

I want to make someting like-

```
A  = 1
B  = 2
...
...
Z  = 26
AA = 27
AB = 28
AC = 29
```

I used ASCII code converter and range function to do that. But didn't worked. In this case.

```
<?php
    $range = range('AA','ZZ');
    print_r($range);
?>

// Returns an array A to Z not AA to ZZ
```

So, Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that incrementing a string using `++` will wrap around back to AA once it reaches Z, and so on from there:

```
<?php
$result = [];
$string = 'A';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 26*27; $i++) {
  $result[$string] = $i;
  $string++;
}
```

=

```
Array
(
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 2
    [C] => 3
    [D] => 4
    [E] => 5
    ...
```

See https://eval.in/825359

Comment: I think you'll need `26 * 27` rows; number of letters in the alphabet squared for `AA --> ZZ` *plus* `A --> Z`

Comment: Good point, edited. I should have paid more attention to the output...

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that works by using range to assign a value [0,25] to each letter by way of an array index. Then add one extra and you're good. The downside is that this won't work for something like AZA but you said you only need 2 letters.

```
    $string = 'ZZ';
    $result = 0;
    foreach (str_split(strtolower($string)) as $letter) {
        $result += array_search($letter, range('a', 'z')) + 1;
    }
    print($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a value to all letters. Then convert the string into an array so that each value in the array is a letter. Then loop over the array, and sum all of the array elements based on the value of the letter.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Will help me.. Somehow

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$test = "AA";
$ascval = array_map('ord', str_split($test));
var_dump(implode("", $ascval));
var_dump(array_sum($ascval));
```

**Yields:**

```
string(4) "6565"
int(130)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ceb1fa2e8cb29c9f9dbf5e6c30db9878941e34ad